# Error 403-forbidden in weblogic server 11g

Tags: weblogic

I installed weblogic server successfully and i created one managed server and i am able to login for administration console..but the problem is whenever i deploy the war file and test with managed server.. i got the error 403-forbidden in browser.. actually i used eclipse with tomcat configuration and that eclipse was generated project structure dynamically.. with that project structure i created war file through  commad prompt and i deploy that into weblogic server.. anything i did in that please can anyone guide me..

Comment: Have a look at the security constraint that should be declared in your web.xml and the security configuration in the weblogic.xml file.
Maybe your security configuration is not completed because something is missing in one of these 2 files

Comment: what is the diff b/w web.xml and weblogic.xml

Comment: web.xml is a j2ee standard ; weblogic.xml is specific to weblogic server